# Finding the closest possible position for a rectangle in a field of rectangles

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx

I am programming on a 2D castle defense and I faced a problem today that I was not able to find a good solution for. See the following picture:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixdT5.jpg

I want to find the closest possible position to place the red rectangle in this field of rectangles without overlapping any rectangles. By closest possible position I mean the position closest to the current mouse position, so generally the closest possible position to any given point.

What is the right algorithm for that problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Hopefully you are using some sort of a grid for positioning your rectangles and not just random floating point values as coordinates because otherwise, this is not going to be calculated quickly...

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimization problem where your constraints are linear and your objective function is (piecewise) quadratic or linear, depending on how you want to define distance from the cursor.

Assuming that the rectangles are defined by
`x_i, y_i, w_i, h_i for i=1..n`
and the red rectangle has size `w, h`, the decision variables are the `x, y` position for the red rectangle.

The non-overlapping constraints are then:

`x >= x_i + w_i` or `y >= y_i + h_i` or `x <= x_i - w` or `y <= y_i - h` for all `i=1..n`

There are multiple ways you could define your objective (the distance of the red rectangle from the cursor):

- proper Eucledian squared distance between the cursor and the nearest point of the red rectangle (results in a piecewise quadratic function I think)
- the Eucledian squared distance from the center of the red rectangle (quadratic)
- Manhattan distance from the center of the red rectangle (piecewise linear)

Then you could use a [quadratic programming solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) or [MILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) (mixed-integer linear programming) solver to find the answer. If the number of rectangles is not too big (say less than a hundred) then it would be quite fast I think even with free solvers like [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) or [LP Solve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/).

Note that to express the constraints properly for these solvers, you might have to transform the constraints and the objective, for example use the [big M method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) for the constraints, or [transform](http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/media/glpk-sos2_02.pdf) your problem to linear objective. This means you will have additional binary variables, and a couple of more constraints (the number of additional variables and constraints will be proportional to the number of rectangles).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer! I think a little bit later I will use your suggestion and implement it by myself (might take some time...I dont want to use any external libraries). For now, I decided to just use a very simple workaround that proved to be sufficient. I just try random positions on a growing circle around the desired position. This is not exact and kind of bruteforce...but terminates fast enough for the use in my game.